# Website is not loaded through Google+ on mobile

Tags: javascript, google-plus, mobile-website

I'm developing a website with a share option.
The website is loaded fine through a share link from Facebook and Twitter but not Google+ (On mobile).

I do see that the website is opened but not loaded completely.
Is there a way to debug this? I already tried google's debug link https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ but it didn't help me.

**EDIT:**

What I mean is that after you publish, go to google+ and click the published content. It should open the website. In my case it opens it but then the page is not loaded completely.

**UPDATE:**

I debugged google plus chrome from my desktop and here is what I found:

There is an exception when trying to initialize auth2:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _.RE is not a function
pZ                                              @ cb=gapi.loaded_1:formatted:1705
jF                                              @ cb=gapi.loaded_1:formatted:1481
_.hN                                            @ cb=gapi.loaded_1:formatted:1770
(anonymous function)                            @ google.js:200
(anonymous function)                            @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
Ea                                              @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:4
b                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
F.(anonymous function).F.(anonymous function)   @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
c                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
(anonymous function)                            @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
Ea                                              @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:4
b                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
F.(anonymous function).F.(anonymous function)   @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
c                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
(anonymous function)                            @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
Ea                                              @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:4
b                                               @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
F.(anonymous function)                          @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
C.(anonymous function)                          @ client:plusone.js?_=1463374618220:10
(anonymous function)                            @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:1
```

Here is my code for initializing gapi and auth:

```
if (!window.gapi) {
        $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/platform.js', function () {
            $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js', function () {
                gapi.load('auth2', function(){
                    gapi.auth2.init({
                        client_id: 'my-client-id',
                        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                        scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read'
                      }).then(function(){
                          auth2 = arguments[0];
                        authPromise.resolve();
                      },
                      function(){
                        authPromise.reject();
                      });
                });

                gapi.load('client', function() { 
                    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1').then(function() {
                        clientPromise.resolve();
                    }, function(){
                        clientPromise.reject();
                    });
                }, function(){
                    clientPromise.reject();
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Julius, How can we check your website. Can you send your link ?

Comment: You can use this: http://eizeenv.drqwvdcawy.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/question/7d195c9e-08f9-433c-abfc-c7f8ffc0053e , there is a shre button in the toolbar on top.

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly on my mobile and desktop. Check the screenshot below taken from my mobile.

[image: Google Plus Share]

Comment: What I meant is that after you publish, go to google+ and click the published content. It should open the website. In my case it opens it but then the page is not loaded completely.

Comment: today, I am unable to get the page, I can see only the header

Comment: Sorry, I was playing with it - here is a new link: http://eizeenv.drqwvdcawy.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/question/78189e53-cf7f-46a3-b1de-aeae9edad258